# Best way to stream video from iPad or iPhone to Macbook ?

Tags: video, appletv, screen-capture, streaming

I am planning to create some app tutorials (screencasts) using Screenflow on my Macbook

The apps are iPhone and iPad apps so I want to show the live app in the tutorial and mix in other aspects which Screenflow lets you do.

I think therefore I just need to get the iPad to stream to a Window on my macbook - then I can capture it.

I have an Apple TV and I think I read that this is the best way to do this -  but not sure the exact set up - can anyone advise?

Comment: The Apple TV will not do this is the way that you're asking, the Apple TV is good for connecting to an actual TV or Monitor not to another Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an iOS 8 device with a Lightning cable (i.e. no iPhone 4S) and Yosemite, you can do this without an Apple TV.

1. Plug in your iDevice to your Mac.
2. Open QuickTime.
3. Click File > New Movie Recording.
4. Select your iDevice as the input source.

[You can find these instructions online with pictures here.](http://www.mactrast.com/2014/10/easily-record-ios-8-devices-screen-mac-running-os-x-yosemite/)

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful , there are links there for non Yosemite too. (I need to upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

I use AirVideo to stream to my computers, it does have a minimal cost and works well.

Comment: Air Video site says it "allows you to stream video from your computer to your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch" but I want to go the other direction - will it do that? http://www.inmethod.com/index.html

Comment: Yes, download the server version for OS X  and your iPhone/iPad will see your Mac as an AirPlay device to stream to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflector to do this. I do it my self. It cost 15 dollars and streams to you computer via AirPlay.

Check it out here.

http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/